# Java Socket connection timeout Error Coming while contacting SMS gateway

Tags: java, http, sockets, sms

Here is the code I am trying to send SMS through the red Oxygen server

Here is the code I am executing below
final String requestURL = "http://www.redoxygen.net/sms.dll?Action=SendSMS";

```
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        stringBuilder.append("AccountId=").append(URLEncoder.encode("****", "UTF-8"))
                .append("&Email=").append(URLEncoder.encode("*******", "UTF-8"))
                .append("&Password=").append(URLEncoder.encode("******", "UTF-8"))
                .append("&Recipient=").append(URLEncoder.encode("******", "UTF-8"))
                .append("&Message=").append(URLEncoder.encode("hello", "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    final URL address;
    try {
        address = new URL(requestURL);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    final HttpURLConnection connection;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) address.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    try {
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(100000000);

    DataOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    try {
        output.writeBytes(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

While executing I am getting the below exception :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:860)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:801)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:726)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:904)
at com.nextenders.server.LoginServlet.SendSMS(LoginServlet.java:143)
```

I tried with increasing connection  `timeout`  and turn off the firewall ...etc but no luck .Can anyone help me to trace the problem ??

Here is the tutorial I'm  following :
http://www.redoxygen.com/developers/java/

The "*******"s  in my code is credentials for the gateway .

Comment: If it can't connect it can't connect, doesn't seem to be to do with the code. You can get to the URL from the computer on which you are running the code, right?

Comment: No there also an empty page with 0000 coming in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a network topology problem. You can't connect to that site from where you are. Some intervening firewall, probably your own, is preventing it. Talk to your netadmin.

Answer (score 0):

The following code runs fine when I have tested it with other websites (as I don't have access your the messaging API):

```
    final String requestURL = "http://www.redoxygen.net/sms.dll?Action=SendSMS";
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        stringBuilder.append("AccountId=").append(URLEncoder.encode("****", "UTF-8"))
                .append("&Email=").append(URLEncoder.encode("*******", "UTF-8"))
                .append("&Password=").append(URLEncoder.encode("******", "UTF-8"))
                .append("&Recipient=").append(URLEncoder.encode("******", "UTF-8"))
                .append("&Message=").append(URLEncoder.encode("hello", "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    final URL address;
    try {
        address = new URL(requestURL);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    final HttpURLConnection connection;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) address.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    try {
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(100000000);

    try {
        connection.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    final DataOutputStream output;
    try {
        output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    try {
        output.writeUTF(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    final InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        final char[] buffer = new char[0x10000];
        final StringBuilder stackBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        final Reader in;
        try {
            in = new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        try {
            int read;
            do {
                read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                if (read > 0) {
                    stackBuilder.append(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            } while (read >= 0);
            System.out.println("Error response code from server. Error was:");
            System.out.println(stackBuilder.toString());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    final char[] buffer = new char[0x10000];
    final StringBuilder stackBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    final Reader in;
    try {
        in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    try {
        int read;
        do {
            read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            if (read > 0) {
                stackBuilder.append(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        } while (read >= 0);
        System.out.println(stackBuilder.toString());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
```

It will `toString` the various streams and has error handling when the stream doesn't connect.
The most important change is using the `DataOutputStream.writeUTF` method rather than just the `write` method - this will ensure than the `POST` data is encoded correctly. I don't think this is your issue as the problem is on `connect`.
The example code you used seems to be unaware of Java naming conventions or best practices to I have tidied it considerably.
The stream reader can be pulled out and into a separate method to avoid duplication.
I would recommend pointing it at another website (I used my work's) and seeing if you get output.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response .But no use ,Still the same exception .:(

Comment: And with a different website?